# How stable is Netty 4?

Tags: java, netty

How stable is Netty 4, at least the parts that implement the HTTP codec, including web sockets? Is that portion just a renaming of packages, or have there been some fundamental architectural changes that make the code unstable?

I need to be able to use the HttpPost functionality from 4. I thought about trying to make it run in 3.4.0, but I am using OpenJDK and trying to drop 3.4.0 in gave me a stack trace because it couldn't load the class sun.misc.Unsafe. Perhaps this had something to do with trying to run this in an OSGi container, but I also looked at the rt.jar file in my OpenJDK install and sun.misc.Unsafe wasn't there. Perhaps just building it and making the sun.misc classes optional in the OSGi headers would help.

Using the Sun VM is not an option here, I need to use OpenJDK.

Comment: This question's answer tends to change over time... I'd like to know the current status of Netty 4. What does "CR2" stand for? "Candidate for Release 2"? It seems that the Netty 4 api is improved in comparison to Netty 3, but then again, how stable is it?

Answer (score 4):

Netty 4.x is not really stable yet. We will prolly break a lot of the API within the next weeks. So unless you know what you do I would not use it yet ;)

The problem with the Unsafe class should be fixed in 3.4.1.Final which should be out this week if everything works out. The fix is related to [this](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/268).

We plan to have a 3.5.0.Final release which will include the HttpPost stuff. We just want to have 3.4.1.Final first. So stay tuned..

Comment: OK, many thanks. I am comfortable with fixing things, though it depends on what exactly you are breaking. Is it just how things are being called, or is it that a lot of functionality just doesn't work?. I will wait for 3.4.1 to update. Any idea on 3.5.0 timeline?

Comment: Good to hear about 3.5.0.Final. When will it be released? Does it include file upload? File upload is the only reason I am using Netty 4 for Xitrum (https://github.com/ngocdaothanh/xitrum).

Comment: @ngocdaothanh yeah it should be also part of 3.5.x

Comment: @user1341438 wewill break the handler api and many more. So I'm talking about big changes... After 4.0.0.Alpha1 it should be more stable. There is no timeline fixed yet but I would expect it to be out soon after 3.4.1.Final is out

Comment: So if I want the file Upload, should I build off of the master branch at this point? Or should I go with the 3.5 branch, and, if so, where is that? All of the branches I found with the org.jboss package didn't have the file upload, only the io.netty.